# Layout Breaks When Switching Devices

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, iphone-x

I have to admit that I'm not a big fan of `Auto Layout`.  But I guess I need to use it because of iPhone X.

Anyway, I have a simple layout.  I have a map view (`MKMapView`) object and a view (`UIView`) object in pink at the bottom.

I have two layout requirements.  (1) The top of the map view must sticks to the safe area.  (2) The bottom of the pink view sticks to the superview.

First, I select iPhone X as a layout device.

As for the map view, I select the safe area and the map view and add align to top edges.  I also add align to left edge and align to right edge.  So I get the following.

[image]

As for the pink bottom view, I select the (super) view and the pink guy to add align to bottom edges.  I then add align to the top, left and right edges.  Also, the height is set to 48 pts.  So I get the following.

[image]

Now, if I switch the layout device to iPhone 8 Plus, the layout will hold.  But if I switch from iPhone X to iPhone SE, it will miserably break as shown below.

[image]

How can I maintain my layout regardless of devices?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't completely replicate what your screenshots show; in particular I can't get the top level View to have the descendant constraint of "Bottom Space to Bottom View".  I suspect you have some other constraints that are causing the conflict.  I think it would be best to start over on this view controller to make sure you don't accidentally add constraints that don't belong.
Drag a Map Kit View and a View into this new controller, rename the View to "Bottom View" and add new constraints to the Map Kit View like this:
[image]

Then add the constraints for the Bottom View like this:
[image]